# How can I get a random result from an array, then based on that result get another random result from another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I have an array

```
firstArray = [ "Blue", "Red", "Green" ];

Red
```

I want to click a button and display a random result from that array, let's say it's "Red". Then based on that result "Red" I want to click a second button and get another random result from another array.

```
blueArray = [ "Sky", "Water", "Jeans" ];
redArray = [ "Apple", "Firetruck", "Rose" ];
greenArray = [ "Grass", "Money", "Leaves" ];

Red - Rose
```

Then I want to click the first button again, get a new result and clear the second button's result.

Comment: "based on the first results".  "based" how?

Comment: same index maybe?

Comment: Please read [ask] and be a lot more specific about what your issue is and what problems you are having achieving it

Comment: @charlietfl I think the updated post makes a lot more sense.

Comment: First question, new to js and jquery. Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: @JonMorris How sould the first random result make an impact on the second random result?
Thats not really clear for me.

Comment: Still no idea what the first selection has to do with second. We can't guess at what you are trying to do

Comment: What I'm trying to do is essentially roll a die, d6. Get a result, 3. Then roll another die, d10. Get a result, 7. I want to display result 3 from the first array, and then result 7 from result 3's sub array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the three arrays in an object whose keys will be in the first array:

```js
var colors = [ "Blue", "Red", "Green" ];                     // colors (keys from items object)

var items = {                                                // each color from colors has an array of items in this object
  "Blue": ["Sky", "Water", "Jeans"],                         // items for color "Blue"
  "Red": ["Apple", "Firetruck", "Rose"],                     // ...
  "Green": ["Grass", "Money", "Leaves"]                      // ...
};


var color = null;                                            // should be here in the outside so it will be accessed by both event listeners (you can initialize it to a color if you want)
$("#first-button").click(function() {                        // when clicking the first button ...
  color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; // ... choose a random color from colors and assign it to the variable color
  $("#color-span").text(color);                              // set the text of the color span
});
$("#second-button").click(function() {                       // when clicking the second button ...
  if(color) {                                                // check if we had chosen a color (using the first button)
    var item = items[color][Math.floor(Math.random() * items[color].length)]; // then choose an item from the equivalent array (if color is "Blue" then items.Blue will be chosen)
    $("#sentence-span").text(color + " " + item);            // set the text of the sentence span (using both color and item
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first-button">First Button</button>
<button id="second-button">Second Button</button>
<p><b>Color is: </b><span id="color-span"></span></p>
<p><b>Sentence is: </b><span id="sentence-span"></span></p>
```

Comment: Yes I think that's very close to what I'm looking for. Just want to simply display each result below the buttons. Thank you!

Comment: @jmorris for both the first and the second button?

Comment: That's right, first button clicked, display "red", then optionally you can click the second button to get the red array result, "apple".

Comment: @jmorris check now!

Comment: Awesome! That's great. Now a follow up question. How do I also display an image with the "Color is: result". In this example I would want to display a blue square along with the word blue. Sorry if this is a basic request, just starting to get my feet wet.

Comment: @jmorris for this particular example you can add `$("#color-span").css("background", color);` in the first event listener right after `$("#color-span").text(color);`. Because the colors are valid CSS color names.

Comment: Maybe a bad example, I actually want to display an image. With the blue, not just the color blue in css.

Comment: @jmorris Then just name the images according to the colors array: `Blue.jpg`, `Red.jpg` ... and use like this: `$("your-img").attr("src", "path/to/images/folder/" + color + ".jpg");`.